# Inserting spatial data into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, spatial, spatial-query

I tried to insert data into point() datatype column from PHP this way:

```
INSERT INTO table (coordinates) VALUES ("48.20 14.80");
```

or

```
INSERT INTO table (coordinates) VALUES ("POINT(48.20 14.80)");
```

And then I applied triggers before every insert or update:

```
BEGIN
SET @lat = SUBSTRING(NEW.coordinates, 1, LOCATE(' ', NEW.coordinates));
SET @lng = SUBSTRING(NEW.coordinates, LOCATE(' ', NEW.coordinates) + 1);
SET @coor = PointFromWKB(POINT(@lat, @lng));
SET NEW.coordinates = @coor;
END
```

or

```
BEGIN
SET NEW.coordinates = GEOMFROMTEXT(NEW.coordinates);
END
```

But it returns:

```
SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1416 Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

Does anyone of you know what's the problem? Thanks.

Comment: check datatype of coordinates

Answer (score 3):

try this:

1-

```
   BEGIN
    SET @lat = ST_X(NEW.coordinates);
    SET @lng = ST_Y(NEW.coordinates);
    SET t.coordinates = GEOMFROMTEXT(CONCAT( 'POINT(', @lat, ' ', @lng, ')' ) ) ... --update point table
    END
```

2-

```
 INSERT INTO table (coordinates) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(48.20 14.80)'));
```

Comment: It works, but only when I add the data manually. I can' figure out how to send "raw" data (the app is based on a framework), that should be executed as a command (ST_GeomFromText(value) in INSERT). So I added immediately after BEGIN this line: SET NEW.coordinates = ST_GeomFromText(NEW.coordinates). And that, of course, doesn't work.

Comment: Does not work because wait `value` should be `text`.

Comment: May I contact you somehow? I have few more questions about that problem.

Comment: Yes, I completed them.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is

1. split the colum coordinate into two colums e.g coord_lat and coord_long and before inserting data into table split the coordinate value into two variables.

OR
2. Change coordinate column data type to text.

Comment: Good solution, but I forgot to mention I would like to have a spatial index applied on that column.

Answer (score 0):

It is kinda late but i created this solution to the problem

```
$cord= $long." ".$lat;
```

And on insert i used this. Note i am using the codeigniter active record to insert data

```
$this->db->set("coord",'geomfromtext("POINT("'."'$cord'".'")")',false);
$this->db->insert("gisdata");
```

Hope it helps. 
Cheers!